# Can't log data from Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo, gql

I using Apollo to fetch data from GraphQL. When I trying to log data from `useQuery` I'm getting two logs first in undefined and second is log with gql data.

When I'm trying to get data from for example `data.flats.title` react I have information that is undefined so it's info from first `console.log()`. How I can get data and show it?

Console Screen:

[image: console screen]

```
import React from "react";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const myQuery = gql`
  query {
    flats {
      Title
    }
  }
`;

const Test = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(myQuery);
  console.log(data);
  return <h2>GQL TEST</h2>;
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: The reason is for that the `gql` call with `useQuery` is asynchronous and it takes time to get back the result. On the first render once you start the request `data` is `undefined`. You can use `useEffect` hook to only trigger logging once you have something in `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need a simple `null` or `undefined` check to represent your data properly. You can either use [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.) or `&&` check.

Based on that you can do in your component with `&&` as the following:

```
const Test = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(myQuery)

  return <>
    <h2>GQL TEST</h2>
    {data && data.flats && <span>data.flats.title</span>}
  </>
}
```

Or with Ternary operator:

```
const Test = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(myQuery)

  return <>
    <h2>GQL TEST</h2>
    {data && data.flats ? <span>data.flats.title</span> : null}
  </>
}
```

Just from the naming of `data.flats` I can assume it can be an array where you need to use similarly as I suggested above just with `.map()` as:

```
{data && data.flats && data.flats.map(e => <span>e.title</span>)}
```